# Duplicate keys when adding products in Vuetify Data Table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently using a Vuetify Data Table where you can add products to. In the end I want to do a calculation based on the price of all those products. The products all have an ID, but when I add those products to the Data Table it gives me the following error:

> Duplicate keys detected: '12'. This may cause an update error.

I understand this happens because I use the ID of the product. But how can I prevent that it is giving me this error? Should I pass a completely different ID instead of the one of the product itself? I might need the product ID later. I would like to know what would be the best solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to add a column with an unique `id`. If you have an array of objects:

```
array.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.subId = i + 1;
})
```

Then in your Data Table set the `item-key` to `subId`.

Comment: Is there a way to use the `index` value of the array?

Comment: @RizaKhan Yes, just use `item-key="index"`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not even have a `id` property in your array of objects.

I had merged two different types of objects together using `flatMap` and it resulted in some duplicate values for the `id` property I had created.

I simply renamed the `id` to something else (ie, `item_id`) and v-data-table then creates its own `id` property on the fly.